# MySQL UPDATE query using two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Using the following tables:

**post_meta**

```
-----
meta_id     post_id     key                 value
-----
22          4546        Advantages          old value
23          4546        Article number      123
```

**posts**

```
-----
id         status
-----
4546       pending
4547       publish
4548       publish
```

I am trying to write an UPDATE query to change 'old value' to 'new value', for posts that are set 'pending' which id corresponds to post_meta's post_id that has 'Article number' set to '123'.

I have no idea how to proceed ... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to change the value of the row with `meta_key = 'Advantages'` from `'old value'` to `'new value'` for the rows with `meta_key = 'Article'` and `value = '123'` for which there exists a corresponding `post_id` in `posts` with `status = 'Pending'` then I think the query you want is this:

```
update post_meta
join (
  select pm.meta_id
  from post_meta pm
  join posts p on pm.post_id = p.id
  where p.status = 'pending'
    and pm.`key` = 'Advantages' -- or pm.value = 'old value'
    and exists (
      select 1 
      from post_meta 
      where post_id = pm.post_id 
        and `key` = 'Article number' and value = '123') 
    ) t on post_meta.meta_id = t.meta_id
set value = 'new value';
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6494fb/1)

With your sample data this would leave the `post_meta` table looking like this:

```
| meta_id | post_id |            key |     value |
|---------|---------|----------------|-----------|
|      22 |    4546 |     Advantages | new value |
|      23 |    4546 | Article number |       123 |
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated query

```
UPDATE post_meta pm, (
    SELECT pm2.meta_id 
    FROM posts p 
    INNER JOIN post_meta pm1 ON p.id=pm1.post_id
    INNER JOIN post_meta pm2 ON p.id=pm2.post_id
WHERE
    pm1.key='Article Number' AND pm1.value = 123
    AND pm2.key='Advantages' AND pm2.value = 'old value'
    AND p.status = 'pending'
) p
SET pm.value = 'new value'
WHERE pm.meta_id=p.meta_id
```

Comment: @jpw, where did meta_id 22 come in to question? the OP wants to update the value for post against "id corresponds to post_meta's post_id that has 'Article number' set to '123'." which is clearly id 23

Comment: Works now, removed my dw.